# How do I achieve independant mixed column layout?

Tags: context, two-column

I'm trying to create my first ConTeXt document.  How can I achieve such a layout with ConTeXt, each part being independant from the others ?

```
——————————————
|   |        |
|   |        |
——————————————
|            |
——————————————
|       |    |
——————————————
```

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53527/why-is-a-page-break-added-at-the-end-of-a-column-set-in-context

Comment: If each part is independent, the easiest option is use tables (either natural tables or tabulate)