# ConTeXt: Suppress blank page in asymmetrical multicolumn layout

Tags: page-breaking, context, columns, emptypage

## Background

Creating a custom multi-column layout having columns that differ in width.

## Problem

This question's problem is mentioned but not addressed in a previous [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483456/context-complex-multicolumn-layout):

> Setting `page=yes` causes an unfortunate side-effect: the book is interwoven with blank pages in between chapters. These can be eliminated using Ghostscript to post-process...

In other words, without the `page=yes` option, ConTeXt is unable to format the text as desired. With the `page=yes` option, ConTeXt formats as expected but exports an undesired blank page between major sections.

## Code

Minimum working example that illustrates the problem:

```
\definepapersize[BookPaperSize][width=24in, height=12in,]
\setuppapersize[BookPaperSize]

\definelayout[BookTextLayout][
  topspace=.5in,
  backspace=.5in,
  header=\zeropoint,
  footer=\zeropoint,
  grid=yes,
]
\setuplayout[BookTextLayout]

\definecolumnset[BookColumns][n=4,distance=.25in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:1][width=11.75in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:2][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:3][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:4][width=3.46in]

\setuphead[section][
  page=yes,
  beforesection={\startcolumnset[BookColumns]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumnset},
]

\setuphead[subsection][
  after={\column},
]

\setuphead[subsubsection][
  after={\blank[small]},
]

\starttext
\startsection[title={Section Title}]
\startsubsection[title={Subtitle}]
\dorecurse{2}{\input knuth}

\dorecurse{2}{%
  \startsubsubsection[title={Subsubtitle}]
    \dorecurse{1}{\input ward}
    \dorecurse{2}{\input lorem}
    \dorecurse{1}{\input bryson}
  \stopsubsubsection
}

\stopsubsection
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

## Actual Output

The page before each section is blank:

[image: Actual Output]

## Output Without Page

When the `page=yes` option is removed, the output has issues:

[image: No Page Command]

The `\column` command no longer appears to respect the column widths and the text bunches up at the bottom of the first column.

## Expected Output

The desired output would not have a blank page between major sections:

[image: Expected Output]

## Work Around

The [resulting PDF](https://impacts.to/) contains multiple pages. Using [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) works to delete every other page (e.g., using `gs -sPageList=even`), which produces the desired result:

[image: Example Output]

- Theory of Inflation by [Roen Kelly](https://roenkelly.com/)
- Stars by [James Josephides](https://www.jjosephides.com/)

However, the extra blank page causes knock-on problems: extra image processing steps, PDF pages need reordering, and increased compile time due to needing two passes.

## Question

What needs to change so that the blank pages are eradicated from the document?

## Ideas

Adding `page=yes` to the `\definecolumnset` and removing `page=yes` from the `setuphead` resolves the issue of blank pages; however, the first page columnset is scrunched to the left. I've attempted to address the issue using:

```
\definecounter[BookPageNumber][
  way=bychapter,
  prefix=no,
]

\definecolumnset[BookColumns][n=4,distance=.25in,page={\doifelse{\rawcountervalue[BookPageNumber]}{1}{}{yes}}]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:1][width=11.75in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:2][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:3][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:4][width=3.46in]

\setuphead[section][
  before={%
    \doif{\rawcountervalue[BookPageNumber]}{1}{\page}
    \incrementcounter[BookPageNumber]
  },
  beforesection={\startcolumnset[BookColumns]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumnset},
]
```

However, this does not produce the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columnsets are spread-based, i.e. when `n=4` you actually have eight columns, namely four on the left page and four on the right page.  A document always opens with a right page which you haven't set up and which is why adding `\page[yes]` helps, because it pushes the content to the left page which is set up.

So just adding columns 5-8 for the right page fixes the problem.

```latex
\definepapersize[BookPaperSize][width=24in, height=12in,]
\setuppapersize[BookPaperSize]

\definelayout[BookTextLayout][
  topspace=.5in,
  backspace=.5in,
  header=\zeropoint,
  footer=\zeropoint,
  grid=yes,
]
\setuplayout[BookTextLayout]

\definecolumnset[BookColumns][n=4,distance=.25in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:1][width=11.75in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:2][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:3][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:4][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:5][width=11.75in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:6][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:7][width=3.46in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:8][width=3.46in]

\setuphead[section][
  %page=yes,
  beforesection={\startcolumnset[BookColumns]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumnset},
]

\setuphead[subsection][
  after={\column},
]

\setuphead[subsubsection][
  after={\blank[small]},
]

\starttext
\startsection[title={Section Title}]
\startsubsection[title={Subtitle}]
\dorecurse{2}{\input knuth}

\dorecurse{2}{%
  \startsubsubsection[title={Subsubtitle}]
    \dorecurse{1}{\input ward}
    \dorecurse{2}{\input lorem}
    \dorecurse{1}{\input bryson}
  \stopsubsubsection
}

\stopsubsection
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

[image]